# Move items on the Safari reading list

Tags: macos, safari

Can I *move* items in the Reading List like I can in the Bookmarks section?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "move"? Are you trying to organize them into folders?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no direct way, but I could export them using Google Chrome:

1. From the `Customize and Control Google Chrome` menu, choose `Bookmarks > Import Bookmarks and Settings`.
2. In that window, select `Safari` and make sure that the `Favorites/Bookmarks` option is checked, then click `Import`.
3. Now, in `Chrome Bookmarks` menu, you should find a new folder called `Imported from Safari` with a subfolder called `com.apple.ReadingList` that include your Reading List items.
4. If you want, you can export them using Chrome's Bookmark Manager as usual.